# Laravel 8 Auto fill after selecting value on dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-8

i problem again..

[if i selected rute banjarmasin-jakarta, biaya pelayaran field will fill 1.750.000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGeWP.png)

But, i want to selected again "cari rute pelayaran" and biaya pelayaran field will fill 0

[selected "cari rute pelayaran" to fill 0 in biaya pelayaran field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldvEN.png)

this my view

```
<select class="form-control select2bs4" id="biaya_pelayaran_id" name="biaya_pelayaran_id"
                            style="width: 100%;">
                            <option value="">Cari Rute Pelayaran</option>
                            @foreach ($biaya_pelayaran as $item)
                                <option value="{{ $item->id }}"> Rute: {{ $item->rute_asal }}
                                    -
                                    {{ $item->rute_tujuan }} || Unit:
                                    {{ $item->unit->nama }} || Biaya:
                                    {{ number_format($item->biaya_pelayaran) }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
   <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="biaya_kapal">Biaya Pelayaran</label>
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="biaya_kapal" name="biaya_kapal"
                                    value="0" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

my ajax/javascript code

```
 $('#biaya_pelayaran_id').change(function() {
        var id = $(this).val();
        var url = '{{ route('getBiayaPelayaran', ':id') }}';
        url = url.replace(':id', id);

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                if (response !== null) {
                    $('#biaya_kapal').val(response.biaya_pelayaran);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

controller

```
public function getBiayaPelayaran($id = 0)
{
    $data = BiayaPelayaran::find($id);
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace your ajax/javascript code with this it may work

> 

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            if (response !== null) {
                $('#biaya_kapal').val('');
                $('#biaya_kapal').val(response.biaya_pelayaran);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).